# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" - npm install react-scripts@latest

Tags: npm, installation, react-scripts

We are experiencing issues upgrading to create-react-scripts 2.

I have no problem running `npx create-react-app`.  App is created and runs fine.

In apps based on create-react-app, `npm i react-scripts@latest` generates:

> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded npm ERR! A complete log of
>   this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-09T19_27_15_671Z-debug.log

In log file:

> 4092 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@xtuc%2flong 426ms
>   4093 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @xtuc/long@4.2.1 404 Not
>   Found: @xtuc/long@4.2.1 4094 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call
>   stack size exceeded

npm: 6.4.1
node: 8.12.0
Windows 10 (but also reproducible in Docker node:8.12.0)

This is the package.json with older react-scripts that works fine:

`...
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-markdown": "^3.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.0.4",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^7.0.4",
    "typeface-lato": "^0.0.54"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/codemod": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/webdriverio": "4.8.7",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.6",
    "chromedriver": "2.35",
    "commander": "^2.15.1",
    "copyfiles": "^1.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "cucumber": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.4.0",
    "eslint": "^5.5.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-nibble": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-webdriverio": "^1.0.1",
    "gherkin-lint": "^2.11.1",
    "jest-junit": "^3.7.0",
    "markdownlint": "^0.10.0",
    "markdownlint-cli": "^0.10.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^4.7.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.6",
    "should": "^13.1.0",
    "wdio-cucumber-framework": "1.0.2",
    "wdio-junit-reporter": "^0.4.4",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.9",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "0.1.2",
    "webdriverio": "^4.13.1"
  }
}`

Changing package.json to read `"react-scripts": "^2.0.4"` and then `npm i` or running `npm i react-scripts@latest` both fail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? I am experiencing it now, myself.